How to efficiently draw to window in wayland
I made a small wayland application, and I'm currently in the process of optimizing rendering performance. Currently to display something I just write to a backing memory file, and tell the compositor to refresh the contents of the window. All examples that I have looked at use this approach, however writing to disk has bigger overhead then just writing to RAM, and in addition knowing that some displays reach over 500hz nowadays writing a fairly large amount of data over 500 times a second to a disk just feels wrong. So I'm wondering if I might be doing something wrong and there might be a better approach.

What graphics/drawing library are you using? (also, in a modern composited desktop environment, window surfaces buffers will exist only in the GPU's memory - not in main-memory - let alone (intentionally) written to disk (unless you're counting the OS paging memory-based surfaces during low-memory situations).

@Dai I'm using a very simple shader that I wrote myself, instead of any graphics library. Nope I'm actually writing to disk to display my image. The file that I'm referring was passed to wl_shm::create_pool as a file descriptor.
So what is essentially going on right now is my shader is creating an image, that is then being mapped to RAM and then I copy the image data to that file to change the image being displayed.
